# Replicating sizing from figma to my css makes everthing larger

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend, figma

I'm a beginner at front end development, i recently joined an early startup as an intern. And I was given a figma design to replicate into a working website. But when I'm copying any size from figma (like padding, margin, etc), the component becomes larger in the site.

Is this problem from developer's end or designer's end? Or is this normal and the scaling just cannot match

I tried to manually decrease the size by multiplying it with a factor of 0.75. That worked and made the website look closer to the designs but i don't think that that's the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your browser zoom level is not above 100%. Using Figma values in your css should not create scaling issues.

For example in Chrome, go to view > Actual Size.